# Mongodb TTL Index not expiring documents from collection

Tags: database, mongodb

I have TTL index in collection fct_in_ussd as following

```
db.fct_in_ussd.createIndex(
    {"xdr_date":1},
    { "background": true, "expireAfterSeconds": 259200}
)


{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "xdr_date" : 1
    },
    "name" : "xdr_date_1",
    "ns" : "appdb.fct_in_ussd",
    "background" : true,
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 259200
}
```

with expiry of 3 days. Sample document in collection is as following

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4808c9b32ewa2f8escb16b"),
    "edr_seq_num" : "2043019_10405",
    "served_imsi" : "",
    "ussd_action_code" : "1",
    "event_start_time" : ISODate("2020-08-27T19:06:51Z"),
    "event_start_time_slot_key" : ISODate("2020-08-27T18:30:00Z"),
    "basic_service_key" : "TopSim",
    "rate_event_type" : "",
    "event_type_key" : "22",
    "event_dir_key" : "-99",
    "srv_type_key" : "2",
    "population_time" : ISODate("2020-08-27T19:26:00Z"),
    "xdr_date" : ISODate("2020-08-27T19:06:51Z"),
    "event_date" : "20200827"
}
```

Problem Statement :- Documents are not getting removed from collection. Collection still contains 15 days old documents.

MongoDB server version: 4.2.3

Block compression strategy is **zstd**

*storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor: zstd*

Column *xdr_date* is also part of another compound index.

**Observations as on Sep 24**

I have 5 collections with TTL index.

It turns out that data is getting removed from one of the collection and rest of the collections remains unaffected.

Daily insertion rate is ~500M records (including 5 collections).

This observation left me confused.

TTL expiration thread run on single. Is it too much data for TTL to expire ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb TTL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976726/mongodb-ttl-not-working)

Comment: No. it doesn't. I have enabled debug logs in mongo server and checking TTL monitoring logs.